# SQL Server 2016 Update a datetime attribute for a row in a table when a change occurs in that row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Basically I have a table with three columns: `Data, DatetimeCreated, DatetimeModified`.

I need to update the `DatetimeModified` attribute with `GETDATE()` any time the `Data` attribute has changed for that row.

How can this be accomplished using an `UPDATE` trigger? Any help is appreciated.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will also need a **primary key** column in your table for this to work - which any serious table should have anyway....

Then you can use this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdateDatetimeModified
ON dbo.YourTableNameHere
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.YourTableNameHere
    SET DatetimeModified = SYSDATETIME()
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.PrimaryKey = i.PrimaryKey
    WHERE d.Data <> i.Data;
END;
```

Based on the `Deleted` (old values before `UPDATE`) and `Inserted` (new values after `UPDATE`) pseudo tables available inside the trigger, it checks to see which rows have an update in the `Data` column, and for those, the `DatetimeModified` is updated.

I'd also recommend starting to use `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` as a best practice.

Comment: Using 'WHERE d.Data <> i.Data' didn't work.  I made the change to 'WHERE d.id =  MyTable.id' and I got the result I was looking for.

Comment: @StanB13: what **datatype** is your `Data` column?

Comment: @StanB13: doing it the way you're doing it just updates all rows that have been updated - regardless of which column(s) was (were) updated. But that's typically also the behavior you want, anyway, right?

Comment: The Data column is typed varchar(15).  There are additional columns in the table that could get updated, so yes, that is what I'm looking for.  I guess you would have picked that up if I had included the additional columns.  Either way you've helped me out tremendously and it's much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: By the way, now knowing that I could update the modified date based on a change in a given column is a bonus.  Thanks again!!